# Excel: return date from days count

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

In a cell I have a starting date (e.g. 01 Jan 2000). What function allows me to print the exact date after an amount of days (01/01/2000+ e.g. 165,728066 days). It should count for months with 28,30 and 31 days of course. It should be something like (~) 15 June 2000

Comment: just use `=A1+165,728066` where `A1` contains your date `01 Jan 2000`

Comment: =1/1/2000+165,728066 result is 165,728566. Not a date..

Comment: write in `A1` cell `1/1/2000` and in `B1` cell `=A1+165,728066`

Comment: It works..! Why it didn't directly in the formula?

Comment: because in `=1/1/2000+165,728066` `/` is devision operator

Comment: If you need to use it directly in formula, try also `=DATE(2000,1,1)+165,728566`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments above, you can use

```
=DATE(2000,1,1)+165,728566
```

or write in `A1` cell `1/1/2000` and in `B1` cell `=A1+165,728566`

Answer (score 2):

`=DATEVALUE("01 Jan 2000") + 165`, formatted as a date will give you the date that is 165 days from 01 Jan 2000.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need a function. You can just add the number of days to the starting date and the result is the the date after the number of days from the starting date.

Say in A1 cell you have the date : 01 Jan 2000.
In A2 cell, input "A1 + 365". The result is 31 Dec 2000 since you have an additional day in February in 2000.

Comment: I tried with 1/1/2000+165,728066 but the result is 165,728566.

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the output cell in date as well. Then you get the date instead of just numbers.